# Black edges artifacts in renders on edges of geometry?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I get these weird black edges in renders. I don't know what the cause of it is. I've gotten them before with really close up shots and low focal lengths, but this image only has a focal length of 25 or so. What could be the cause?

In the image below, you can see it along the edge of the wave at the bottom just to the left of center.

[image: black edges in render]

Comment: Please attach blend-file.

Comment: How do I attach the file? I don't see a link?

Comment: Put it somewhere online and link to it. For instance dropbox or pasteall.

Comment: Link to the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtfl4rhne0as4rw/Ocean%20Sunrise%2001.blend

Comment: I have examined the file and find nothing wrong with it. The black area change with ior of your ocean material. I don't know enough about optics to know what this means. It could be a bug, or an optical phenomenon. Sorry.

Comment: I believe this is caused by [total internal reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Internal_Reflection)

Comment: Thanks guys,

I think it most likely a bug. I found the file where I also had the issue. Focal Length 15 - "Macro" shot. You can see the black artifacts on the bottom front edges of the brush. No refraction in the materials. Only Difuse+Gloss.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovq9uglwfogkaze/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-08%20at%204.11.38%20AM.png

I'll submit a bug report.