# Shading artifacts in low poly models in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I am talking about Cycles. Why does it produce shading artifacts on low poly models in smooth shading especially close to the edges? I usually fix them by adding more vertices, edge splitting etc but why is this required and is it the only way? I've noticed that in game engines or some other 3D apps the shading on the same models looks fine.

Here's a small example in Cycles
[image]

Here's the exact same mesh in another render engine
[image]

Comment: because of normals ( there are similar questions here )

Comment: The normals of the models are pointing the right way if thats what you mean.

Comment: can you upload an image?

Comment: Sure, I just did.

Comment: Another solution is to add extra geometry (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7864/599) so as to avoid heavily interpolated normals which seem to be the cause of this

Comment: Sadly adding geometry defeats the purpose of doing low poly work. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @user40079 If you're looking for a low poly style, then perhaps you might want to turn off smooth shading. If you just want to keep the poly count down, then I'd suggest that cycles is the kind of render engine where it's perfectly excepted to feed it mid to high poly meshes even for small or relatively simple objects. Trying to render super low poly meshes realistically (like you would in real-time renderers) may not work so well