# Glass shader appears black when touching another object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

Here are renders of the glass:

[image] [image]

As you can see, the first image looks fine, but when the glass is broken and on the ground it appears black. How do I fix it? I have never had this issue in any other renders with cell-fractured glass.

Here is the material node setup:

[image]

Comment: related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/black-patches-in-glass-when-using-cycles-render-engine

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: None of the answers suggested in that question solve it.

Comment: @jBot-42 Please upload the .blend

Comment: I already answered the question, but I can't accept the answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, caustics were disabled, and turning them on fixed the problem.