# Black holes / Water in glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I try to render mineral water bottle filled with water in Cycles. For testing purposes I use super simple model with absolute flat lighting filled with white color.

What is bothering me are the black spots on the render. I mean, I know there should be some strange curves generated by IOR, but in the complete white environment black patches should`nt appear.

What should I do, to avoid them? I`m attaching images with the render result.

[image: Watter in the bottle]

I know that lighting and model are dull, but I use them to exclude any unnecesarry factors. My render settings are:

[image: render settings]

---

This is my latest bottle atempt with photo lighting. It looks better, but on the top of the bottle strange curves appeared. I think that it is caused by plastic rings on the bottle, but it look unnatural. I think that I`m missing something, because I still dont have control on this render behavior.

[image: latest result]

Comment: Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/black-patches-in-glass-when-using-cycles-render-engine. Also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass/35741#35741

Comment: I'd say this result is normal.
My guess: it's caused by the refraction from the bottom of the cap.

Comment: See http://adaptivesamples.com/2013/10/19/fluid-in-a-glass/

Comment: I`ve seen all this articles. In fact, the bottle I created as a result of the last tutorial (adaptivesamples.com). Unfortunately, it does`nt solve my problem.

Comment: I once saw a tutorial on water in a glass (it may have been by @AndrewPrice), where it was said that the water and the container should overlap slightly, so the edge of the water should be between the outer and inner edges of the container. This avoids both Z fighting and getting pockets of air between the water and the container.

Comment: change the ior of the glass perhaps to unrealistic high numbers

Answer (score 1):

These "black spots" are actualy supposed to be there. [image]

Look at these images with similar dark spots

[image]

It is actually more prevalent in thicker objects so if you really don't like it, try making the glass thinner
[image: sadf]
This images has a glass with much thicker walls.

Comment: You`re right. I just have impression that this black holes should be much lighter. The photos, that you are showing are made in photo studio with black areas (just assuming), but in the complete white environment there should not be any black patches.

Comment: @andrew Did you try making the plastic thinner?

Answer (score -2):

Check the hdri lighting with this seen !

Hope this will work for you ! check it [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEPBg.jpg)